# "Black Cab Driver" sketch

Tags: dialect

[Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzBrJnckrfY&list=PL229ABA3863C39B50&index=12)

Hale and Pace. Scottish comedy duo. Sometimes even the locals don't get it when they do dialect, what shall poor German me say. Sometimes Czech subtitles help :-)

The linked sketch is especially ineffable (or was that inscrutable). The first song verse I get (he evidently likes playing golf), the second too (I googled what bish-bash-bosh means), but the third could as well *be* in Czech...

Can someone with a good grasp of London (black cab driver?) dialect enlighten me?

Comment: This video is unavailable in the UK

Comment: Also, not Scottish, they were from the London Suburbs.

Comment: Sadly we are barred from viewing that YouTube sketch in the UK by the copyright holders, ITV. Without using a VPN we can't answer your question.

Comment: "Indecipherable" is the word.

Comment: I am a native speaker of American English. I have no idea what they are singing except that a bunch of white dudes are pretending to be black. I need subtitles. I suspect that the joke is that most speakers of British English find the pronunciation peculiar but comprehensible. When I was young, we had a cleaning woman whose native language (creole?) was Gullah. She would vam the room, meaning to vacuum it. We could communicate, but most English speakers could not.understand her at all.

Comment: @JeffMorrow What makes you think they're pretending to be Black?  I'm a native speaker of American English too, and they don't sound remotely Black to me, at least not like Black Americans.

Comment: Because they sing “I’m a Black cab driver.” And they are not supposed to be speaking Black American English but rather Black London English.

Comment: @JeffMorrow - It would be 'African-American Cab Driver' if that was what they meant. We're not that backwards in the UK.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - "African American" in the UK? Surely not!

Comment: @KateBunting ;-)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey No, I had not presumed it was African American. I was responding to a question.

Comment: @JeffMorrow - I was facetiously suggesting that nervous white Americans might want to call a black London cab an 'African-American cab'.

Comment: Sorry. Missed the joke. Some days the mind just does not click. The whole thing about black cab drivers coming across as drivers of black cabs in the U.K. and as black drivers of cabs is amusing. Two peoples divided by a not quite common language. Sorry to be dim.

Comment: @JeffMorrow - I have updated my answer, as thanks to the Tor proxy server running on my Raspberry Pi, I have been able to see the video.

Comment: To the OP, if you want to see something which is _actually funny_, why not try The Fast Show?

Comment: There is apparently a video clip of an interview where a (White, American) interviewer asks a Black British athlete what his victory meant to him as an African-American...and then when he points out he's not American, she "corrects" herself to say "British African-American"!

Comment: @stangdon - are there Americans who are really that stupid?

Comment: @stangdon - in the interests of balance, I had an English colleague once who thought that Canada was a state in the USA, 'near Chicago'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I'm a German, how shall *I* know what British find funny? Hale&Pace (and some other comedy show I don't remember the name) were run by ARTE with German subtitles way back then. Recently found some Youtube videos (some with Czech subs :-) and gave it a rerun since I always found Hale&Pace riotously funny. The window wiper, oh the window wiper (google "umyvac")..."The Fast Show" I only vaguely know by name. (And THX for the thorough answer.) P.S. Had I guessed the confusion, I somehow had marked that black is an adjective to cab, not driver - in German this isn't ambiguous :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regularly comes up in language discussions and just as regularly amuses Britons.

I have, thanks to certain software, managed to see the Youtube video. **It was a painful experience.**. Summary: the sketch, and the song it contains, are a barrage of 'Cockney slang'. This is the whole point of the thing. Nobody is 'black', or pretending to be. The only black thing is the cab which is driven on stage, and the alleged 'driver' is actually a lower-level TV comedy actor of the era.

The song is based on three Cockney slang phrases, one per verse:

1. 'Play a blinder' - perform some task or feat very well
2. 'Bish-bash-bosh' - said to indicate the completion of a task with efficiency.
3. 'A large portion, yes' - said to indicate enthusiasm for something or someone who is attractive. Note the gestures. Also the third verse ends with a reprise of the first two.

Hale and Pace in Cockney Geezer outfits (they are actually quite posh) - they are wearing black cab driver's licence badges on cords around their necks:

[image]

A black cab driver is someone *of any race or colour* or who drives a **black cab**. These are mainly used in London (where they are compulsory for taxis which can be hailed from the streets). They are of old fashioned appearance because they have to have plenty of headroom (there is a story that historically there had to be room for a man's top hat). They also used to be mostly black (hence the name).

There is a stereotype that the drivers tend to be conservative-minded working-class 'Cockney geezers'. They have to have very extensive (tested) knowledge of London streets.

Hale and Pace are humorously mocking 'Cockney' accents and slang, using assumed broad London accents.

[image]

Comment: Excellent and thorough answer. I wouldn't say that they specialised in Cockney humour though - they weren't from London. Gareth Hale was from Hull; Normal Pace was from the midlands. But they often lampooned various regional dialects, northerners as much as southerners.

Comment: @Astralbee - Thank you. Good old Normal Pace! Nothing weird about _him_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Great answer. And the previous comment presumably refers to an old but good (and now presumably wildly incorrect) joke.

Comment: @JeffMorrow - it refers to Astralbee's spelling of Norman Pace's first name as 'Normal'.